# Location service in iOS

Tags: ios, service, location

I get a pop-up saying that so and so app is continuously tracking your location. How do I prevent this from appearing on screen? When the user is using the app for the first time, I have no problem with this message. But I get it later on after some days. How do I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prevent it. It is part of the privacy and location functionality in iOS. It reminds the user that they have granted your app permission to use location in the background and that your app has been doing so. It gives the user an opportunity to change their mind about your apps location permissions

Comment: Oh.. ok .. I thought I can prevent it asking user's permission frequently. Thank you!